# How to transform the data from one to another in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have following data

```
    Mar-22  Mar-22  Apr-22  Apr-22
Dimension 1 Dimension 2 AB  CD  AB  CD
X       Y       1   2   5   6
P       Q       3   4   5   7
```

which has to convert to below

I have to initialize a header Date

```
Dimension 1 Dimension 2 Date    AB  CD
X       Y       Mar-22  1   2
X       Y       Apr-22  5   6
P       Q       Mar-22  3   4
P       Q       Apr-22  5   7
```

Comment: What is `print (df.columns)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.set_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html) for convert columns to datetimes, then use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) for new column name `Date` and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), last convert `Date`s to original format by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([('Mar-22', 'AB'),
            ('Mar-22', 'CD'),
            ('Apr-22', 'AB'),
            ('Apr-22', 'CD')],
           )

print (df.index)
MultiIndex([('X', 'Y'),
            ('P', 'Q')],
           names=['Dimension 1', 'Dimension 2'])

df.columns = df.columns.set_levels(pd.to_datetime(df.columns.levels[0], 
                                   format='%b-%y'), level=0)

df = (df.rename_axis(['Date', None], axis=1)
      .stack(0)
      .reset_index()
      .assign(Date = lambda x: x.Date.dt.strftime('%b-%y'))

print (df)
  Dimension 1 Dimension 2    Date  AB  CD
0           X           Y  Mar-22   1   2
1           X           Y  Apr-22   5   6
2           P           Q  Mar-22   3   4
3           P           Q  Apr-22   5   7
```